# Any initState() replacement present in the Provider ecosystem?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider, flutter-bloc, riverpod

#### Question:

I want to build my app using no stateful widgets and I have a necessity of using initState(). I would be grateful, if anyone from the community can help me with this challenge.

Is there any replacement for the initState() function in the provider package?

Comment: u can use Condition to overcome. like when a page gets open call a function & based on it return a widget. Like if Loading then show this if not this..

Comment: How can I achieve this using the "Provider" package?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) package.

The method `useEffect()` is the equivalent of `initState` + `didUpdateWidget` + `dispose`.

```dart
useEffect(() {
      // This is "initState". Run your methods here
      uiController.getData();

      // We could optionally return some "dispose" logic here, ex., 
      // return subscription.cancel;
      return null;
    }, const [
             // here specify custom keys that will rebuild the widget. It's "didUpdateWidget"
             ]);
```

As an example, we could use hooks to manually implement a fade-in animation, where a widget starts invisible and slowly appears.

If we were to use StatefulWidget, the code would look like this:

```dart
class FadeIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const FadeIn({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<FadeIn> createState() => _FadeInState();
}

class _FadeInState extends State<FadeIn> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController animationController = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Opacity(
          opacity: animationController.value,
          child: widget.child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Using hooks, the equivalent would be:

```dart
class FadeIn extends HookWidget {
  const FadeIn({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Create an AnimationController. The controller will automatically be
    // disposed when the widget is unmounted.
    final animationController = useAnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    );

    // useEffect is the equivalent of initState + didUpdateWidget + dispose.
    // The callback passed to useEffect is executed the first time the hook is
    // invoked, and then whenever the list passed as second parameter changes.
    // Since we pass an empty const list here, that's strictly equivalent to `initState`.
    useEffect(() {
      // start the animation when the widget is first rendered.
      animationController.forward();
      // We could optionally return some "dispose" logic here
      return null;
    }, const []);

    // Tell Flutter to rebuild this widget when the animation updates.
    // This is equivalent to AnimatedBuilder
    useAnimation(animationController);

    return Opacity(
      opacity: animationController.value,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no initState in a stateless widget but you can call a function after rebuild of a stateless widget using this:

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    // do something
    print("Build Completed"); 
  });
  
    return Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: WhatEverWidget()
    );
  }
}
```